# docker compose volumes not contains files

Tags: docker-compose

Before adding the volumes command, the container build and run normally. I can see the files are installed in the container's `/var/www/html`.

But, I want to make custom code and so want to mount a local folder to `/var/www/html`.

However, when I bring up the container (docker-compose up), no files are copied to my local folder.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
web:
    image: wordpress
    links:
     - mysql
    environment:
     - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=rootpass
    ports:
     - "80:80"
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
     - ./html:/var/www/html
mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=rootpass
     - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```

Comment: What files are you expecting to see on your host? Unless your running container copies them into the volume, there isn't going to be anything put into the volume.

Answer (score 0):

where are the files you are looking for?  in ./html?  if there are files in /var/www/html within the container they will be hidden when mounting a volume from the host.

The other issue I have run into is if you are using docker-machine to connect to a remote host,  the files must be on the remote host not on your local workstation.

Comment: docker-machine should create a shared volume to allow you to use files on the local machine, but I think it only does /home/$USER by default. You can always add additional shared folders

Comment: That's may be a feature of your VM container. Virtual box fusion etc. it's not the norm if you are using something like gcp or digital ocean.

Comment: Oh, you are correct. I think it's only for the virtualbox driver.

Comment: There are some php files in the container's /var/www/html. But I want to sync it to the local folder /html so that I can edit it directly using the IDE tool and reflect in the container for testing immediately. How to make the files in container appears in the mount local folder?

Comment: Copy them out of the container to your linked folder   You could also use docker inspect to find out where on the file system the files are really located.   Also are you using a virtualization layer with boot2docker or docker machine ?

Comment: I am using docker machine.

Comment: With docker machine no matter what you do the files will be on the machine not the host. You may be able to map this if your machine has a common share with your workstation.